# Infinity getchar with reallocation

Tags: c

hi i am a trying to make the console read characters and increase the size with realloc until i hit ctr+z and end the loop.The terminal is displayng segmentation fault.The program should work like this:

```
f
f
f
f
f
f
```

Hit ctrl + z
print the characters.
How to fix this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
    int size = 2;
    char* buffer = NULL;
    buffer = (char*) malloc(size*sizeof(char));
    if(buffer==NULL)
    {
        puts("Allocation failed");
    }

    printf("Enter character: ");
    while(1)
    {
        buffer = getchar();
        size++;
        buffer = (char*) realloc(buffer,size*sizeof(char));
         if(buffer==NULL)
    {
        puts("Allocation failed");
    }
    }
    
    printf("%c",buffer);
    free(buffer);
    

}
```

Comment: buffer = getchar(); should be giving you compiler warnings... `getchar()` returns an `int` and this clobbers the pointer to the allocated heap memory... You want some kind of indexing or something to put the character into the buffer, not slam the buffer's address...

Comment: Please do not change your question in such a way that it invalidates existing answers. For example, please do not apply the bug fixes recommended in an answer to the code in the question, because this invalidates the answer. I have reverted your edit in which you did this.

Comment: Side note: It is highly inefficient to call `realloc` every time you increase the capacity of the buffer by a single byte, because the entire buffer may have to be copied every time you call `realloc`. A more efficient algorithm would double the size of the buffer whenever the capacity is exceeded. That way, it is guaranteed that not more than `n * 2` bytes will have to be copied, where `n` is the total number of characters. However, as long as you are dealing with small amounts of input, this is not an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`buffer = getchar();` should be giving you compiler warnings...
`getchar()` returns an `int` and this clobbers the pointer to the allocated heap memory... 
You want some kind of indexing or something to put the character into the buffer, not slam the buffer's address..

You're struggling with this. It's important to note that `realloc( NULL ...` acts just like `malloc()`, so you can "grow" the array from zero as needed calling realloc from just one location.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int ch, size = 0; // trust me
    char *buffer = NULL;

    printf( "Enter characters: " );
    while( ( ch = getchar() ) != EOF ) {
        char *tmp = (char*)realloc( buffer, (size+1) * sizeof *tmp );
        if( tmp == NULL ) {
            puts( "Allocation failed" );
            exit( 1 );
        }
        buffer = tmp; // the possibly new memory address
        buffer[ size++ ] = (char)ch; // the new character just entered.
    }

    // NB: buffer is NOT a null terminated C string.
    // It is an array of characters that can be printed, though.
    printf( "\nGot this: %.*s", size, buffer );
    
    return 0;
}
```

```
Enter characters: Quick Brown Foxes ^Z

Got this: Quick Brown Foxes
```

Comment: The code comment `// trust me` does not seem very helpful. Something like `// the return value of "getchar" must be stored in an "int", not a "char"` may be better.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Feeling slutty, I've added the comment virtually unaltered... The `trust me` is to draw attention to the (surprising to beginners???) idea of starting with nothing and using `realloc()` instead of `malloc()/realloc()`... Adds a bit of drama :-) (PS: Thx... It's slim pickin's these days here on SO...)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
buffer = getchar();
```

This:

```
*buffer = getchar();
```

But you should also support detecting for EOF in case of redirected input:

```
while(1)
{
    int result = getchar();
    if (result == EOF)
    {
        break;
    }
    *buffer = (char)result;
```

Comment: Yeah,i saw that after i post this but i am wondering how i can end the while loop with ctr + z and then print the buffer.

Comment: `*buffer = getchar();` That would always assign to the first byte of the buffer.